# How to make xrandr scrreen resolution permanent?

Tags: bash, resolution, xrandr

I create script file name it `lightdmxrandr.sh`. here is file content:

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LDVS-0 1024x768_60.00
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --off --output LVDS-0 --mode 1024x768_60.00 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --off
unity --replace
```

and in terminal write: `bash home/kakao/lightdmxrandr.sh` the I got following error

```
kakao@kakao-dro:~$ bash /home/kakao/lightdmxrandr.sh
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  29
xrandr: cannot find output "LDVS-0"
xrandr: cannot find mode 1024x768_60.00
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 2960
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
Killed
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must use xrandr to make sure that the new mode can fit within the maximum framebuffer size:

```
xrandr | grep maximum
```

Later you must use gtf to create a mode line:

```
gtf 1024 768 60.00
```

Below you can add new mode using xrandr:

```
xrandr --newmode "1024x768_60.00"   63.50  1024 1072 1176 1328  768 771 775 798 -Hsync +Vsync
```

Now you can add this newly added mode to the desired output (VGA/LVDS)

```
xrandr --addmode LDVS-0 1024x768_60.00
```

And now you must choose the new mode

```
xrandr --output LDVS-0 --mode 1024x768_60.00
```

Once you have verified that everything works fine, you can just create the script to make de changes persistent.

Answer (score 1):

The output name is not correct:

```
xrandr: cannot find output "LDVS-0"
```

You can find the right output name with:

```
xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

In my case:

```
eDP-1 connected primary 1864x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
```

I.e. I have to use *eDP-1* as the output name.

Answer (score 0):

BadName may occur, if the name is already defined.

I also ran into this problem with badname yesterday and wrote a little bash-script that thinks for me ;-)

It creates modelines on the fly, if needed, chooses the output automatically, if possible and therefore might solve your problems directly.

https://github.com/philippkemmeter/set-resolution